# Custom boundary value for ContentType multipart/form-data - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data, content-type, form-data

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744353/how-to-set-my-own-boundary-on-multipart-form-data-using-xmlhttprequest-and-formd), and several other similar posts, but none have addressed my query.

Going by [rfc spec](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) for Multipart Content-Type, there is unique boundary value required to be set as header and to be used in the payload as well separating the different elements in the body.

How to add custom boundary value for multipart/form-data using jQuery. Presently the browser adds the default boundary value and I want to use a predefined value.

```
   var boundaryVal = 'boundary02018983645'
  var formData = new FormData()
  // '--' + boundaryVal
  formData.append('document', app.components.document[0])
  // '--' + boundaryVal
  formData.append('documentName', app.components.document[0].name)
  // '--' + boundaryVal
  formData.append('documentDescription', vWeb.forms.components.document[x].name)
  // '--' + boundaryVal
  formData.append('documentActivityDate', moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  // '--' + boundaryVal + '--'
  ajaxRequests.push(function () {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred()
    app.services.postFileUpload({
      data: formData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;boundary=' + boundaryVal
      },
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      parseData: false
    }).done(function (data) {

    }).fail(function () {

    })
    return deferred
  })
```

Browser adds the below boundary val

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryKAf4ulYAAiTnWDMW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="Map_2017.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundaryKAf4ulYAAiTnWDMW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documentName"

Map_2017.pdf
------WebKitFormBoundaryKAf4ulYAAiTnWDMW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documentDescription"

Map_2017.pdf
------WebKitFormBoundaryKAf4ulYAAiTnWDMW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documentActivityDate"

2018-12-07
------WebKitFormBoundaryKAf4ulYAAiTnWDMW--
```

but I want it to be custom defined like this

```
------boundary02018983645
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="Map_2017.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------boundary02018983645
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documentName"

Map_2017.pdf
------boundary02018983645
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documentDescription"

Map_2017.pdf
------boundary02018983645
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documentActivityDate"

2018-12-07
------boundary02018983645--
```

Comment: as far as I know that is uncontrollable, webkitformboundry is been added by the chrome. and why do you want to change it anyway?

Comment: @Just code - the file being uploaded goes to a third party for malware detection and that system requires a custom boundary value to process the file, hence.