# Reactjs | How to make boundary static when content type is multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

We are facing one issue while we are making file upload post call using React-JS, in dev-tools under form data we are getting some browser generated boundary.

```
------WebKitFormBoundarypSTl3xdAHAJgTN8A
```

[image]

And because of this random boundary we are getting issue while we are making call to a third party api.

Is there any way to make this boundary some fixed value. Something like this :

```
----somefixedvalue.
```

Here is the js code:

```
function doupload() {
let data = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
console.log('doupload',data);
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", data);
fetch('http://localhost:8081/upload/multipart',
{
method:'POST',
body: formData,
headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----somefixedboundary'
  }
}).then(res => {
       for(const header of res.headers){
           console.log(`resHeaderName: ${header[0]}, Value:${header[1]}`);
         }
     });
alert('your file has been uploaded');
location.reload();
```

};

can someone help me to solve this? I'm quite confused here as i have given content type along with some static boundary but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a file to the binary string and prepare the body by yourself instead of using `FormData` as it shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68080804/1180397).

But keep in mind that if this `----somefixedvalue` substring appears in the file it will be considered a boundary causing body parsing error on receiver side. In case of FormData, browser should take care of it and prevent this.